# Access div class in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and I am quite confused about it. I have here the div. It has a lot of div classes because it has each attribute. I want to access the dropdown div and append something to it using javascript. I have done appended it when it was outside of the div classes but when it got inside the div of the body I cannot access it anymore. What is the problem? Here is the code of the home.html which contains the div of dropdown.

html code:

```
            <div class="main_bg"><!-- start main -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main row">
            <div class="col-md-3 images_1_of_4 text-center">
                <span class="bg"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
                <h4><a href="../view/index.php">Reports</a>
                <div class = "dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" role="button"  data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
  </a>
</div></h4>
                <p class="para">This is the list of reports.</p>
                <a href="../view/index.php" class="fa-btn btn-1 btn-1e">Records
        <div id="underInput" />
           </div></a>
            </div>
```

javascript code:

```
 $(".main_bg").find($(".container")).find($(".dropdown")).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-bell-o').append("<a  href='../view/index.php' >" +
            "<span class='glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-trash img-circle text-danger' width='50px'>"+
            "</span>Delete</a>");
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsbin.com/hojogitema/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Your code at the moment is using the .append() method on the result of the .removeClass method which you're calling on the i element with class 'fa fa-bell-o'.  You can do what you need with the following (simplifying the above code a bit):

```
var dropdownDiv = $('.main_bg .container .dropdown'),
    glyphElement = dropdownDiv.find('fa');

glyphElement.removeClass('fa-bell-o');

dropdownDiv.append(YOUR_INJECTED_HTML_GOES_HERE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you directly use:

```
$(".dropdown").removeClass('fa-bell-o').append("<a  href='../view/index.php' >" +
            "<span class='glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-trash img-circle text-danger' width='50px'>"+
            "</span>Delete</a>");
```